# Run method from different class with variables from current class

Tags: java, class, parameter-passing, call

I need to run a method from a different class but I want to use the variables for the method from the class I am going to call the method from. I don't want to pass parameters in as there are too many variables for the method and also, it would ruin my code for the original class.

An example of my code is as follows -

Class to run method from

```
variable1;
variable2;
variable3;
otherClass OC = new OtherClass();
otherClass.method();
```

and the so called 'otherClass' method (the class with the method), is for example

```
variable1;
variable2;
variable3;
public void method()
{
 //DOES STUFF WITH variable1 variable2 and variable3
}
```

what i want it to do is run the method with the variables from the class in which I am calling the method, i.e. the class for the code i posted first. Is there any way to do this?

Comment: So create a container class to hold your data members, populate that, and pass in that object to your calling method.

Comment: you need is not very clear. Why do you want to pass parameters to your method ?

Answer (score 3):

As OldProgrammer said, a proper solution is to use a container to encapsulate all variables your methods need.

An example:

```
public class ContainerClassExample {

    private static class Container {
        Object variable1, variable2, variable3;

        public Container(Object variable1, Object variable2, Object variable3) {
            this.variable1 = variable1;
            this.variable2 = variable2;
            this.variable3 = variable3;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] argv) {
        Container aContainer = new Container("a", "b", "c");
        methodA(aContainer);
        System.exit(0);
    }

    public static void methodA(Container input) {
        // Do something with variable1, variable2, and variable3
    }
}
```

Greater is the number of the input parameters, more I suggest you to use the [builder pattern](http://www.javaworld.com/article/2074938/core-java/too-many-parameters-in-java-methods-part-3-builder-pattern.html) to create your container.